# Proof of monotonicity of conditional expectation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-expectation

I am trying to show monotonicity of conditional expectation. Namely, if $X\leq Y$ almost surely, and $\mathcal{M}$ is some $\sigma$-algebra then $\mathbb{E}[X|\mathcal{M}]\leq\mathbb{E}[Y|\mathcal{M}]$. I know that $\forall E \in \mathcal{M}$,

$$\int_E \mathbf{E}[Y|\mathcal{M}]-\mathbf{E}[X|\mathcal{M}]dP \geq 0$$

Thus, consider the set of elements for which $\mathbf{E}[Y|\mathcal{M}]-\mathbf{E}[X|\mathcal{M}] < 0$ denoted $G$, on this set, $\int_G \mathbf{E}[Y|\mathcal{M}]-\mathbf{E}[X|\mathcal{M}]dP< 0$ which implies that $G\notin \mathcal{M}$.

I would like to say then that $P(G)=0$, but since $G$ is not in the $\sigma$-algebra I don't even know if it is measurable. What am I missing here? How do I know that this set has zero measure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\field}{\mathscr{M}}$

Let $G$ be defined as you described. You cannot derive $G \notin \field$ -- in fact, because $E[Y|\field] - E[X|\field]$ is $\field$-measurable, it is certain that $G \in \field$.  One correct way to show the monotonicity is via proof by contradiction as follows:

By the definition of $G$, we have that $(E[X|\field] - E[Y|\field])I_G \geq 0$ everywhere.  If $P(G) > 0$, then

\begin{align}
 & P[(E[X|\field] - E[Y|\field])I_G > 0] \\
=& P[[(E[X|\field] - E[Y|\field])I_G > 0]\cap G] + P[[(E[X|\field] - E[Y|\field])I_G > 0]\cap G^c] \\
=& P(G \cap G) + P(\varnothing) = P(G) > 0.
\end{align}

It then follows (as we have just shown that the non-negative random variable $(E[X|\field] - E[Y|\field])I_G$ has positive probability of being positive) by Theorem $15.2$ of *Probability and Measure* that

$$\int_G (E[X|\field] - E[Y|\field])dP = \int (E[X|\field] - E[Y|\field])I_GdP > 0,$$
which contradicts with $\int_G (E[Y|\field] - E[X|\field])dP \geq 0$.  Therefore $P(G) = 0$, i.e., $E[Y|\field] - E[X|\field]) \geq 0$ almost surely.

Comment: For convenience, I cite the theorem used in the answer here: *Suppose $f$ is non-negative, if $\mu[\omega: f(\omega) > 0] > 0$, then $\int fd\mu > 0$*.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing  something, but by the definition of G, don't we have $(E[X|M] - E[Y|M])I_G > 0$? And then assuming $P(G) > 0$, $$\int_G (E[X|M] - E[Y|M])dP$$ would be an integral of a strictly positive function on a set of positive measure, so it should be strictly positive, which contradicts $\int_G (E[Y|M] - E[X|M])dP \geq 0$? Can you explain why it is necessary to show that $P[(E[X|M] - E[Y|M])I_G > 0] > 0$?

Comment: @tornt I think I was trying to matching the condition of the cited theorem precisely.  What you suggested should also work, as it naturally implies that condition.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $E(X|\mathcal{M})$ and $E(Y|\mathcal{M})$ are $\mathcal{M}$-measurable. Therefore, the set
\begin{equation*}
G = \{x | E(X|\mathcal{M}) > E(Y|\mathcal{M})\}
\end{equation*}
**is $\mathcal{M}$-measurable**.

Now, since $G \in \mathcal{M}$,
\begin{equation*}
0 \leq \int_G (Y - X) \,\mathrm{d}P = \int_G (E(Y|\mathcal{M}) - E(X|\mathcal{M}))\, \,\mathrm{d}P \leq 0.
\end{equation*}
Therefore,
\begin{equation*}
\int_G E(Y|\mathcal{M}) \,\mathrm{d}P = \int_G E(X|\mathcal{M}) \,\mathrm{d}P.
\end{equation*}
And this implies that $P(G) = 0$.