# If $\int_A f d\mu = \int_A g d\mu$ $\forall A \in \mathcal{F}$, then $f=g$ a.e.

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, analysis, probability-distributions

> **Theorem 16.10.** (i) If $f$ and $g$ are nonnegative and $\int_{A} f d \mu=\int_{A} g d \mu$ for all $A$ in $\mathscr{F}$, and if $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite, then $f=g$ almost everywhere.
>
> **Proof.** Suppose that $f$ and $g$ are nonnegative and that $\int_{A} f d \mu \leq \int_{A} g d \mu$ for all $A$ in $\mathscr{F}$. If $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite, there are $\mathscr{F}$-sets $A_{n}$ such that $A_{n} \uparrow \Omega$ and $\mu\left(A_{n}\right)<\infty$. If $B_{n}=[0 \leq g<f, g \leq n]$, then the hypothesized inequality applied to $A_{n} \cap B_{n}$ implies $\int_{A_{n} \cap B_{n}} f d \mu \leq \int_{A_{n} \cap B_{n}} g d \mu<\infty$ (finite because $A_{n} \cap B_{n}$ has finite measure and $g$ is bounded there) and hence $\int I_{A_{n} \cap B_{n}}(f-g) d \mu=0$. But then by Theorem 15.2(ii), the integrand is 0 almost everywhere, and so $\mu\left(A_{n} \cap B_{n}\right)=0$. Therefore, $\mu[0 \leq g<f, g<\infty]=$ 0 , so that $f \leq g$ almost everywhere; (i) follows.

I am really not understanding this proof. Why do we consider the set $B_{n}=[0 \leq g<f, g \leq n]$? Don't these sets miss out on the values of $g$ which are greater than $f$? Moreover, how does $f\leq g$ a.e. immply $f=g$ a.e.? It seems there is a case they are missing here.

Comment: the other case is totally symmetric

Comment: @Exodd Are assuming that $f\leq g$? or are proving this in cases for each set?

Comment: This type of the question is so similar to the one you asked [before](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4507483/proof-of-monotonicity-of-conditional-expectation).  Both questions are quite straightforward application of Theorem 15.2(ii)).  I suggest you spending a little more time on digesting similar questions before casting a new one.

Comment: @Zhanxiong Thank you very much for you answer on my last question. Both used similar concepts, but I believe them to be fundamentally different questions. It seems I need to review some basic properties of the Lebesuge Integral so reading these proofs is smoother.

Comment: @SamKirkiles This type of questions can be summarized at high-level as follows: " Condition: $\int_A f d\mu \leq \int_A g d\mu$ for all $A$. Goal: $f \leq g$ a.e.".  In other words, to prove $P[f > g] = 0$.  The tactic is proof by contradiction (though the author may skip intermediate steps) -- try eliciting contradiction if we assumed $P[f  > g] > 0$.  A natural next step is then to take $A$ in the condition to be the set $[f > g]$ and then nail the proof with non-negativity of integrand and Theorem 15.2(ii).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is $f=g$ almost everywhere if their integrals over any subset are the same?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3489956/is-f-g-almost-everywhere-if-their-integrals-over-any-subset-are-the-same)